# How do I refactor a calendarViewModel such that it's not tied to a specific controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For a small Angular.js testbed project, I've set up the following plunker:

[My Plunked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FTpVHZfMVJ0P3GMOXGwV)

Originally, I had a local version of this testbed working, when the `calendarViewModel` was directly included in the Angular controller.

```
appControllers.controller('PageController', [
    '$scope', '$http', 'Enums', 'ViewModels',

    function ($scope, $http, Enums, ViewModels) {
        var calendarViewModel = function () {
            var pub = {};

            pub.date = new Date();
            pub.isOpen = false;

            pub.today = function () {
                if(pub.isOpen)
                    pub.date = new Date();
            };

            pub.clear = function () {
                if(pub.isOpen)
                    pub.date = null;
            };

            pub.hide = function () {
                pub.isOpen = false;
            };

            pub.toggle = function ($event) {
                $event.preventDefault();
                $event.stopPropagation();

                $scope.hideCalendars();
                pub.isOpen = !pub.isOpen;
            };

            return pub;
        };

        // Backing model for this 'controller'
        $scope.viewModel = {
            // Properties:
            startCalendar: new calendarViewModel(),
            endCalendar: new calendarViewModel(),

            // data:
            // Generates an object that is sent to the server with $http calls.
            data: function () {
                var object = {
                    startDate: startCalendar.date.toString(),
                    endDate: endCalendar.date.toString()
                };

                return JSON.stringify(object);
            }
        };

        // - Controller-specific functions... ----------------------------------
        $scope.hideCalendars = function () {
            $scope.viewModel.startCalendar.hide();
            $scope.viewModel.endCalendar.hide();
        };

        $scope.clear = function () {
            $scope.viewModel.startCalendar.clear();
            $scope.viewModel.endCalendar.clear();
        };

        $scope.today = function () {
            $scope.viewModel.startCalendar.today();
            $scope.viewModel.endCalendar.today();
        };

        // Restricts certain days from being selected.
        $scope.disableWeekends = function (date, mode) {
            return mode === 'day' 
                   && (date.getDay() === Enums.DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday 
                      || date.getDay() === Enums.DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday);
        };

        // This is a demonstration scope action.  Pretty much, the pattern
        // I found, is to have a view model expose a method that creates
        // a stringified JSON blob that we can send to the server.  This
        // method is how such a save function would work.
        $scope.save = function () {
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/some/server/url',
                data: $scope.viewModel.data()
            });

            promise.success(function (data) {
                // Do something with the returned data?
            }).error(function (data) {
                // Do something with the error data?
            });
        };
        // - End of Controller-specific functions... ---------------------------

        // Picker-specific options...
        $scope.dateOptions = {
            'starting-day': Enums.DaysOfTheWeek.Monday,
            'format-day': 'dd',
            'format-month': 'MM',
            'format-year': 'yyyy',
            'min-mode': Enums.PickerMode.Day,
            'max-mode': Enums.PickerMode.Year
        };

        $scope.format = 'MM/dd/yyyy';
        $scope.today();
    }
]);
```

Since I refactored it out to the `ViewModels` constant object, though, I get the following errors from Angular:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.pub.toggle (http://run.plnkr.co/AKUBdEb5M3KT5DM9/app.services.js:31:4)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:10185:21
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:17835:17
at Scope.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:11936:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:12036:23)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:17834:21)
at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:2613:10
at forEach (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:310:20)
```

The reason I am doing this, is because in theory multiple controllers could have need of calendars that are tied to `calendarViewModels` (this is why I created the `calendarViewModel` functional object in the first place.)  I want the `calendarViewModel` construct to not be tied to a specific controller, however, which I have apparently broken by refactoring it in this way.

I think I'm on the right track, but in any event, something is clearly missing.  My **question**: what is the correct way for me to refactor my `calendarViewModel`, that works and is more easily reusable?

Comment: why don't you create a directive that abstract all the logic for handling calendars? look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/FVfSL/

Comment: The reason I am not doing that, is because I am specifically trying to use the Angular UI for Bootstrap package; the team I am on has already settled on both Angular and Bootstrap, and I am evaluating a package that, naturally, plays nicely with both.  While your example is cool, and worth keeping in mind, it dosen't really help me with this problem.

Comment: You have an extra `;`, plunker is even telling you about it...

Comment: Good catch, but I'm still having a JavaScript exception getting thrown.  I'm updating the original post with the new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a few things from your plunker:

- Don't use app.constant to do factories. Use app.factory instead, eg:

_

```
appServices.factory('ViewModels', function() { 

    var pub = {};

    pub.date = new Date();
    pub.isOpen = false;

    pub.today = function () {
        if(pub.isOpen)
            pub.date = new Date();
    };

    pub.clear = function () {
        if(pub.isOpen)
            pub.date = null;
    };

    pub.hide = function () {
        pub.isOpen = false;
    };

    pub.toggle = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        //hideAll();
        pub.isOpen = !pub.isOpen;
    };

    return pub;

});
```

- Your factories are automatically shared between controllers when you do this:

_

```
appControllers.controller('FirstController', [ '$scope', 'MyCalendarService', function($scope, MyCalendarService){
  $scope.myCalendarService = MyCalendarService;

}]);

appControllers.controller('SecondController', [ '$scope', 'MyCalendarService', function($scope, MyCalendarService){
  $scope.myCalendarService = MyCalendarService;

}]);
```

... if the controllers are defined in parallel in the html. If they are nested, you just need to inject your service at the top level. Ideally, you just need to DI a couple of services in a controller and assign them to the scope.

Does that answer your question?

PS: `hideAll` is not defined in your plunker, I commented it out and things started to work.

Edit: This edited plnkr should do what you want: http://plnkr.co/edit/7VDYDQhK2CDGnwa8qhWf?p=preview

Comment: The problem with merely commenting out the `hideAll` is that I need it to only show one calendar at a time - `hideAll` is a function that I tell the `calendarViewModel` about so that it knows to use that function to close all of the calendars, before performing the `isOpen` toggle.  Would you mind showing a forked version of my original plunker, so I can better understand how everything you've talked about works together?

Comment: @AndrewGray I am starting to understand better what you are trying to do. Give me some time to edit your plunker.

Comment: @AndrewGray I got a working version or at least something closer to what you want. Let me know if you need me to go further.

Comment: That updated plunker really helps.  I didn't know that `$rootScope` supported a messaging system.

Comment: @AndrewGray do not abuse of broadcast though. It's an 'expensive' method.